# bargaining game information/equlibria/gametree/normalform

Tags: game-theory, nash-equilibrium, extensive-games

I have a game with two players, player one offers player two one of two cars, car 1(M) has value 2 and car 2 (H) has value 1. Player two can accept (A) or reject (R) the offer. Now I have to answer some questions:

1. Has the game perfect/complete information?
2. Draw the game tree
3. Determine subgame perfect Nash equlibria by backward recursion
4. Reformulate the game in normal form
5. Determine all pure Nash equlibria

ad 1) I would say the game has perfect information, because each player knows at the time of decision exactly in which decision node he is and each information set contains exactly one decision node. If the game hast complete information I am not sure, I have learned that a game has complete information if all players are familiar with the structure of the game tree - but I don't know if for example player two knows that player one also had the opportunity to choose the other car?

ad 2)my game tree: (Is it okay?)

[image]
ad 3)[image]

The red lines are the backward recursion - player 2 chooses the both lines where he has the highest payoff, then player 1 chooses the line where he has the highest payoff. Then the  Nash equlibria is M,(A,A)

ad 4) normal form:

[image]

ad 5)the pure Nash equlibria I see in the normal form if I choose in both raws the value which is highest for player one, that would be AA and AR. The best response is 1 - so a pure equlibria is (2,1)

So now I would be happy if someone can tell me if my answers are right and what I have wrong and how I can change my answers to make it right :)

Comment: Your description of the game seems incomplete. It doesn't mention the payoffs in all possible outcomes and it doesn't mention the information structure (does either player know the quality of the car?).